# Factory pattern - how to generate empty class decleration in factory class

Tags: objective-c, dynamic, runtime, forward-declaration

I have a factory class which has an init method like

```
+(instancetype)initWithDictionary:(NSDictionary);
```

in the implementation something like

```
@class ClassA,ClassB,ClassC,.... lots and lots of classes; // like 20+
@implementation

+(instancetype)initWithDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dictionary
{
    NSString *factoryKey = dictionary[@"some useful key to create a class"];
    Class theCorresondingClass = [self classForKey:factoryKey];
    return [[theCorrespondingClass alloc] initWithDictionary:dictionary];
}

-(Class)classForKey:(NSString *)key
{
    static NSDictionary *classesDictionary;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        NSArray *classes = [[ClassA class],[ClassB class],[....],.....]; // the 20+ class from above
        NSArray *keysForClasses = [@"KeyA",@"KeyB,....]; // the 20 keys for the classes
        classesDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:classes forKeys:keysForClasses];
    }
    return classesDictionary[key];

}
```

Problem is that I am alloc initing from a forward declaration (in the dictionary it is an error) which is a compile time error - The only solution I see possible is to import all the classes into the factory - which seems like a bad move - because ideally I would like the factory to support registration by other classes - such that it will create those classes in runtime - Or define all the classes in the factory - which seems even worse -

The thing is that all classes inherit from a common base class so I know that in runtime it will be defined properly (the alloc init method)-

Is there some way to do a `@dynamic` definition on the class name? perhaps create a macro which stubs an empty class in the factory class?

How does apple do something like that in `NSTextCheckingResult.h` factory?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `NSClassFromString` to obtain a class dynamically.

`classesDictionary` would map keys to class names:

```
classesDictionary = @{ @"KeyA" : @"NSString",
                       @"KeyB" : @"NSNumber" };
```

Then obtain the Class object for a given class name:

```
Class theClass = NSClassFromString(classesDictionary[key]);
```

You may want to perform additional checking to ensure the Class object is a value you expect.  E.g.

```
if ([theClass isSubclassOfClass:[MyBaseClass class]])
    Etc...
```

You would then only need to include the header to the common base class.

Comment: Ok, so just store them as a string? would I loose compile checks?

Comment: Yes, that's the tradeoff.  That's why you should check to return value of NSClassFromString to ensure you have a valid class.